# Telerik controls not responding to .text. What else can i use?

Tags: c#, telerik

I have this line of code I'm stumped on

```
OFXDownloadLink.NavigateUrl = "OFXDownload.aspx?acctID=" + acct.index + 
"&downloadFrom=" + fromDate1.Text.Split(' ')[0] + "&downloadTo="
 + toDate.Text.Split(' ')[0];
```

fromdate1.Text.split is giving me an error on text

> 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadDatePicker' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadDatePicker' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is the alternative for this line?  I see nothing useful in the documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: What platform are you on? Windows Forms, ASP.NET?

Comment: ASP.NET is what this is on.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have to get at the value using a helper class:

```
DateTime value = RadControlHelper.ExtractDateValue(Request, "RadDatePicker1");
```

armed with the `value`, now you can do this:

```
value.ToString().Split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to all this.  What would value be?

Comment: @TheDizzle, `value` would be the value that was in the `RadDatePicker1`.